# How can I identify the currency symbol in a string that has both symbol and value in?

Tags: php, formatting, currency

I'm getting data into a script via XML (not important)... Part of the data is a value amount that includes the currency symbol and the amount, for example:

```
["price"]=> string(6) "$65.00"
["price"]=> string(8) "€14.20"
```

Now, I'm looking for a way to automatically work out which bit is the currency symbol and which bit is the value. I can't guarrantee the quality of data coming in, for example the amount could be £14,000.22 or the symbol may be not just a single letter - ie Swiss Francs - CHF.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I tried this code which worked for the dollar symbol but not the euro symbol:

```
if (preg_match('/\p{Sc}/',trim($price),$matches)) {
                var_dump($matches);
}
```

output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "$"
}
```

For reference I looked at http://www.xe.com/symbols.php for a list of the worlds currency symbols.

Comment: Your problem is the encoding.

Comment: I agree - however the encoding is out of my control, so was looking for other ways to accomplish the seperation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what the exact source data you are dealing with. However, in accounting, there are different formats for different currencies. For example some currencies would prefix their currency symbol. Others would suffix the symbol. Depending on the language of the currency, you might also have different symbols for decimal.

```
/^(\D*)\s*([\d,\.]+)\s*(\D*)$/
```

The above regular expression (JavaScript flavor, you might need to escape it to convert it into PHP), would match the following:

- €14,20
- $65.00
- 65.00USD

Comment: I altered it slightly for my use however this was the one I used compared to the others (all were good)

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you the amount in `$matches[2]`, and the currency symbol or alpha representation will always be in `$matches[1]` or `$matches[3]` respectively.

```
$values = array("$5.00", "€1.23", "£1,323.45", "1.23USD");
foreach($values as $val)
{
    preg_match("/([^0-9.,]*)([0-9.,]*)([^0-9.,]*)/", $val, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using [sscanf()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) rather than a preg function

```
$price = "$65.00";
list($symbol, $price) = sscanf($price,'%[^0-9]%s');
var_dump($symbol);
var_dump($price);

$price= "€14.20";
list($symbol, $price) = sscanf($price,'%[^0-9]%s');
var_dump($symbol);
var_dump($price);

$price= "CHF1,357.99";
list($symbol, $price) = sscanf($price,'%[^0-9]%s');
var_dump($symbol);
var_dump($price);
```

Comment: I don't know if it was true back in 2011, but you don't need `list()`; `sscanf()` lets you write the two reference variables as parameters 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Following simple regular expression might help

price

```
  grep -o '[0-9.,]*'
```

Symbol

```
  grep -o '[^0-9.,]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Number Format in PHP 5.

Requirements:

- **(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PECL intl >= 1.0.0)**

Sample Code:

```
$Format = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE);
echo $Format->format("$1928.77");
```

Homepage: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: Unfortunately php cannot be upgraded on this machine (its on 5.2.6) - good solution though.